# Moving blog to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

So I have tried to implement some solutions to my dilemma but they have all partially failed.

I have moved my blog from www.website.com/blog/ to blog.website.com

blog.website.com is in a directory outside of my root web directory

All urls are identical after the initial location: for example...
old site  www.website.com/blog/wp-admin   =    blog.website.com/wp-admin

This is a wordpress site if that helps or makes a difference.

This is what I have for now.  Redirects main folder but not subfolders...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if not already blog.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.website\.com$ [NC] 
#if request is for blog/, go to blog.website.com
RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://blog.website.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `(.*)`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if not already blog.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.website\.com$ [NC] 
#if request is for blog/, go to blog.website.com
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.website.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was close...  Thanks again